# What would be an experimental test of Sciama’s theory and why it has not been pursued yet?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, dimensional-analysis, inertia

Recently I came across [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpQ0T7rDWm0) were the origin of inertia was attributed to [Sciama’s paper (1953)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1953MNRAS.113...34S/abstract).
I have seen only a couple of [questions regarding this topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/743188) on Stack Physics. Both of them are showing some level of confusion, e.g., it is not clear [why Sciama used G=1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/392507) at times, but not at other times, or that it predicts a critical density that is out of a factor of two (I am not sure if this is too much, given the conditions of predictions Sciama was working with).

However, despite being seminal, Sciama’s work is still largely unknown and somehow a fringe theory. The confusion around the questions on Stack, or the rarity of questions linked to it, is even more convincing to me that Sciama’s paper (with only 300 citations from ADS) is underrated or has flaws I can’t see.

Why has Sciama’s theory not been experimentally tested? And what would be a possible test for it?

Comment: What experimental result motivates this theory?

Comment: @JohnDoty, wouldn't be also valid to ask what results invalidate it?I think the idea was to introduce a concept for the origin of inertia, which is unknown as of yet, and that would motivate it in my understanding.

Comment: Inertia is a concept that unifies models of a wide range of observations. The observations are its foundation. But if you had a theoretical concept for its origin, then what would it stand on? You'd need another theoretical concept to support it. "Turtles all the way down."

Comment: @JohnDoty, are you saying it's actually bad to explain the origin of inertia? :) Jokes aside, I am not sure I can follow your argument. It would be nice if you could write an actual answer on this, whatever your opinion.

Comment: “All models are wrong, some are useful.” -- George Box. Unless you have observations motivating a concept, it isn't physics. It may be math (nothing wrong with math), but it has no physical significance.

Comment: Please provide a link to the video you came across, so we have more context for the question.

Comment: @DavidBailey, thanks. edited.